# enyo with javascript function outside

Tags: javascript, enyo

i have a content in enyo which i want to change dynamically. I have named it Name

```
{name:"Name", content: "", style: "font-weight: bold; line-height: 30px"},
```

I have a function in another js script which gets the content dynamically and send its back to a js function on this page. I am getting the content back correctly (i.e the variable result has content) but i do not know how to then assign it to the content variable as the function is a js function outside of the enyo functions.

I thought something like this would work but it doesnt. Basically i want to know how i can set the Name value from  outside the enyo.kind. var name is not getting defined.

```
function setName(result){

   var name = parent.$.Name;
name.setContent(result);
}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear..share jsfiddle link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This perhaps not the right way in Enyo to do things..But just so you wanted, I have made it work. You may take a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/42m9kd27/

```
//Kind definition in separate JS file
enyo.kind({
name:'Parent',
components:[
    {name:'Name', content: "OldContent", style:"font-weight: bold; line-height: 30px"}
]
});

// Another JS file 
var a= new Parent();           //Get kind object reference
a.renderInto(document.body); 
function Change(result){
    a.$.Name.setContent(result);  
};
Change('NewContent');
```

Comment: I understand its not ideal but thank you for making it work. Much appreciated